# more specific error message with bulk insert save exception

Tags: oracle, exception, bulkinsert, oracle11gr2

```
    declare
      e_forall_error exception;
      pragma exception_init(e_forall_error,-24381)
          ;
      type t_numbers is table of emp.empno%type;
      l_numbers t_numbers := t_numbers(null,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
          ;
    begin
      forall i in 1..l_numbers.count save exceptions
  --note:empno is primary key     
      insert into emp
       ( empno      , ename
       )
       values
       ( l_numbers(i)
       , 'Name' || to_char(l_numbers(i))
       )
         ;
   exception
   when e_forall_error then
     for i in 1..sql%bulk_exceptions.count
     loop
       dbms_output.put_line('SQLCODE: ' || sql%bulk_exceptions(i).error_code);
       dbms_output.put_line('SQLERRM: ' || sqlerrm(-sql%bulk_exceptions(i).error_code));
       dbms_output.new_line;
     end loop;
   end;
   /
```

HI all , i have an exisiting procedure which is inserting the value of empno and empname into emp table as shown above,but the problem is that the error mentioned by the procedure is

```
SQLCODE: 1400
SQLERRM: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ()
```

I want a more specific error ,what it usually throw like

```
SQLERRM: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into empno column
```

How can this been possible in bulk insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE logs (logcode NUMBER, logmsg VARCHAR2(1024));
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE logme(I_logcode IN NUMBER, I_logmsg IN VARCHAR2) IS
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
    insert into logs (logcode, logmsg) values (I_logcode , I_logmsg);
    commit;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insertmyrow(I_prm1 IN VARCHAR2, I_prm2 IN VARCHAR2, ...) IS
BEGIN
    insert into emp  (empno, ename, ...) values (I_prm1, I_prm2, ...);
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN                
    logme(sqlcode, sqlerrm);
    RAISE;
END;
/

forall i in 1..l_numbers.count save exceptions
    insertmyrow(l_numbers(i), ...);
```

This is the main idea and I guess a bit heavy maybe but why not?

Comment: :So why there is a need of `save exceptions` in this proc

Comment: because otherwise at the 1st problem it will stop the further inserts

Comment: :Is there any other way because my insert contains 40 column an different case condition ,and to make this dynamic will be pain for me

Comment: :and i have done a POC on this ,it is throwing me error `PLS-00440: FORALL bulk IN-bind variables cannot be used here`

Comment: why that?? just replace the "insert into emp  (empno, ename) values (:1, ''Name'' || to_char(:2));" in the middle by your one and only query, then bind the columns... you have to do it only once :-)

Comment: Actually I don't know why you get this error. But anyway, I'm having another idea in mind, gonna edit later

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11718/discussion-between-gaurav-soni-and-sebas)

Comment: :Have you tried this script?,its not working again getting the same error `PLS-00440: FORALL bulk IN-bind variables cannot be used here`

Comment: this is a theoretical sript, so, no. But I'm sure this is the way l_numbers(i) is used. This is just a little problem, but the whole thing is the valid idea to solve your problem.

Comment: Obviously you have to use the `forall` in a `BEGIN..END` block!.. right?